# How to fix migration when upgrading from django-ldapdb 0.9.0 to django-ldapdb 1.3.0 (in debian buster)?

Tags: django, django-ldapdb

I ran into an issue when upgrading my web application from django-ldapdb 0.9.0 to 1.3.0 (because it is packaged in Debian Buster). It creates migrations that fail.

It seems that django-ldapd enforce `dn` as a primary key for the models (see [here](https://github.com/django-ldapdb/django-ldapdb/issues/115#issuecomment-287743893), but I don't want to hack django-ldapdb nor can I avoid migrations in my app ), so I tried removing the existing primary key in the model, but that didn't work...

Here is an example of one of the models creating buggy migrations (worked fine in 0.9.0) :

```py
class LdapServiceUserGroup(ldapdb.models.Model):
    """
    Class for representing an LDAP userservice entry.

    Un group user de service coté ldap. Dans userservicegroupdn
    (voir dans settings_local.py)
    """
    # LDAP meta-data
    base_dn = LDAP['base_userservicegroup_dn']
    object_classes = ['groupOfNames']

    # attributes
    name = ldapdb.models.fields.CharField(
        db_column='cn',
        max_length=200,
    )
    members = ldapdb.models.fields.ListField(
        db_column='member',
        blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So when running `makemigrations` it creates a migrations which set `dn` as a primary key. And then :

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 292, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server ver
sion for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")
```

(full error is [here](https://pastebin.com/aYtKmye7) but not really relevant)